# Drag the UIView

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiview, draggable

Drag a UIView within the some frame let us say (0, 0, 320, 190). How can I drag the UIView with an offset. i.e. when I touch the UIView ,the UIView should move not under the  finger.

With an offset the UIView should move and within above frame. How can I do that ?

Please let me know ideas?

Comment: touchesmoved : I override it and set the touch point as the center

Comment: method - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

Comment: Can you please post your implementation?

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
 
  
  UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
  CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self]; 
  
 
  CGFloat xDiff =   touchPoint.x - mTouchStartPoint.x;
  CGFloat yDiff =   touchPoint.y - mTouchStartPoint.y;
  
  self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + xDiff, self.center.y + yDiff);
  
  
    
  
  
  
}

Comment: What exactly does not work? How does it behave and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please update your question and format it. Don't post so much code in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

first use maybe a pan gesture recognizer to pick up where your finger is, and calculate the x and y axis changes between the [gesture locationInView:parentView] which is the location of your finger, and the subview's frame position. adding your offset to this value.

with the x, y changes you just calculated, use UIView animateWithDuration and inside it using CATransform3DTranslate to do a translation. then the subview will move (with animation) to where your finger + offset is.

to keep it inside the parent view, just make sure the translation doesn't cause the subview's frame to go out of the bounds of the parent view, and clip the parent view so any part of your subview going outside of your parent view will not be shown.